# Remarkable and odd property, why is $\sum_{k=1}^i(-1)^{(i+k)}\text{ }^iC_kk^j= 0$ for $i>j$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

At A-level I'd have regarded this as "why I like maths" because it worked, but now I look at it and think "It doesn't look like it should work" and question that.

I am showing $$\sum^m_{k=1}\text{ }^nC_k a_{k,m}=n^m$$ so that I may show sums of integers raised to powers have nice expressions.

I have concluded $$a_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^i(-1)^{(i+k)}\text{ }^iC_kk^j$$

This is correct and truly a lovely bit of maths, but what is funny is that when $i>j$ it is zero. This makes perfect sense based on how I got to it, I do not *doubt* it is zero it's just looking at it, I can find no reason *why* it ought to be zero. (If I gave you this, how would you show it is zero, going back the way I came is not.... intuitive, I couldn't make the leap that it was zero, without knowing how I got to it)

### **Why it is zero (you don't have to read this bit)**

You can see it ought to be zero without touching matrices by looking at the first equation, notice that $^nC_k$ will be a polynomial of order k, the coefficient are such that if you expanded the sum with these polynomials, it would tidy to $n^m$. You would not want an order $>m$ in the mix! (it is because $a_{k,m}=0$ for $k>m$ that the first summation stops at m, rather than being a full matrix multiplication). The matrices involved are $C_n$ an $nxn$ matrix with $(C_n)_{i,j}=^iC_j$ multiplied by $A_n$ the $nxn$ matrix of my unknown magic numbers (the $a_{i,m}$s), and that equals what I call the "power matrix", which is the $nxn$ matrix $P_n$ where $(P_n)_{i,j}=i^j$, thus $C_nA_n=P_n$ giving me $A_n=C^{-1}_nP_n$

The inverse of $C^{-1}_n$ is remarkably nice. $(C^{-1}_n)_{i,j}=(-1)^{i+j}(C_n)_{i,j}$ which is how I found this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your sum is zero when $i>j$ is that your sum represents the number of surjective mappings from a set with $j$ elements to a set with $i$ elements, and of course there are no such maps when $i>j$.

But why does your sum represent the number of surjective maps? To prove it, use the [principle of inclusion exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_inclusion-exclusion). Suppose $X$ has $j$ elements and $Y$ has $i$ elements. Let $U=Y^X$ be the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ and for any $y\in Y$ let $F_y$ denote the set of functions in $U$ which do not contain $y$ in their image. The number of surjective functions is exactly the number of functions not in $\bigcup_{y\in Y} F_y$, and this is
$$\sum_{K\subseteq Y} (-1)^{|K|}\Big|\bigcap_{y\in K} F_y\Big| = \sum_{k=0}^i(-1)^k\cdot T(k),$$
where $T(k)$ is the number of functions in $U$ whose image contains exactly $i-k$ elements. A basic counting argument shows that $T(k)=\binom{i}{k}(i-k)^j$. It follows that the number of surjective functions is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^i(-1)^k\binom{i}{k}(i-k)^j.
$$
Replacing $k$ by $i-k$, this is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^i(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{i-k}(i-(i-k))^j = \sum_{k=1}^i(-1)^{i+k}\binom{i}{k}k^j.
$$

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just noticed this! I've yet to get to this part in my combinatorics book, I'm excited to get through the material now! I only have the one book, can you recommend any? (Rusell Merris' combinatorics)

Comment: I don't know much in the way of combinatorics. Wilf's book [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf) is an absolute classic for generating functions, which are a very useful combinatorial tool.